# A linear projection in a normed space is bounded iff its kernel and image are closed

Tags: functional-analysis

As the title says I want to know if the result is true, ie, if a linear projection in a normed space is bounded iff its kernel and image are closed.

I know the result is true if the space is complete but I cannot prove nor find a counterexample in the non-complete case.

Any ideas?

Comment: Any linear map, on any normed linear space (complete or not) is bounded if and only if its kernel is closed. This is a standard and fundamental theorem of functional analysis, and a straightforward exercise if you haven't seen it before. If $P$ is a projection, then $\operatorname{Im} P = \ker (I - P)$, and $P$ is continuous if and only if $I - P$ is.

Comment: @TheoBendit Are you saying that a linear map from a normed linear space to itself is bounded if and only if the kernel is closed? One direction holds, but the other (kernel is closed implies bounded) fails in general.

Comment: @DeanMiller On second thoughts, I might have been thinking about linear functionals. I'll leave my comment up, just in case someone makes the same error I did.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The claim is true on Banach spaces due to the closed graph theorem.
It is not true on non-complete spaces.

Here is an example. Take $c_{00}$ - the space of sequences of real numbers with at most finitely many non-zero entries - supplied with some $l^p$-norm,
$p$ does not matter. Then it is not complete.

Define $T:c_{00} \to c_{00}$ by
$$
Tx = (x_1 - 2x_2, 0, x_3 - 4x_4, \dots, x_{2k-1} - 2k\cdot x_{2k},0, \dots).
$$
Then $T$ is a multiplication with a block-diagonal matrix, with projection matrices on the diagonal. And $T^2=T$.

$T$ is unbounded, as $T e_{2k} = 2k \cdot e_{2k-1}$. The image of $T$ is the closed linear subspace
$$
im \ T = \{x \in c_{00}: \ x_{2k}=0 \quad \forall k\}.
$$
The kernel is also closed,
$$
\ker T = \{x\in c_{00}: \ x_{2k-1} - 2k\cdot x_{2k}=0 \ \forall k\ge1\}.
$$
Both sets are closed, as both are the intersection of  kernels of linear and continuous functionals.